# Need to extract 3 values from string

Tags: java, string

I receive values like this from database table.

String DBValue = "AssessmentID-289_ApplicationName-OneCert_AccountName-9000032"

From this string I want to extract the values of AssessmentID, ApplicationName and AccountName and store it in these String variables "Assessment_ID","Application_Name" and "AccountName".

Note:
I won't be able to do any changes in database.

Comment: You can use regex `(?<=-).*?(?=_|\z)` to find text between '-' and '_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `String#split`

Call [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) multiple times.

1. First split on the LOW LINE (underscore) character `_` to get the three fields.
2. Then on each of those fields, call `split` on the HYPHEN-MINUS character `-` to split into two parts: field name and field value.

```java
String dbValue = "AssessmentID-289_ApplicationName-OneCert_AccountName-9000032" ;
String[] fields = dbValue.split( "_" ) ;  // Produces "AssessmentID-289", "ApplicationName-OneCert", and "AccountName-9000032".
Map< String , String > results = new LinkedHashMap<>() ;
for( String field : fields )
{
    String[] parts = field.split( "-" ) ;   // Produces pairs "AssessmentID" & "289", "ApplicationName" & "OneCert", and "AccountName" & "9000032".
    if(parts.length >= 2) {
        results.put( parts[0] , parts[1] ) ;  // key is field name, value is field value.
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/AcL2tw).

> results.toString(): {AssessmentID=289, ApplicationName=OneCert, AccountName=9000032}

If you make a method to perform this chore, I would suggest returning an [unmodifiable map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable). Call [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)).

```
return Map.copyOf( results ) ;  // Return an unmodifiable map.
```

Better yet, in Java 16 and later, return a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to transparently and immutably communicate data. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
public record Assessment( String id , String applicationName , String accountName ) {}
```

Return an object of that type.

```java
return new Assessment(
    results.get( "AssessmentID" ) ,
    results.get( "ApplicationName" ) ,
    results.get( "AccountName" ) 
) ;
```

In real work, I would throw in some calls to [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), verify the expected size of the map, and perform some other data validation.

---

Sounds like the source database was badly designed, burying multiple values within one field. Consider educating the responsible person about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).